# Visual Studio 2010 Database projects!

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am looking to use a database project in visual studio 2010 so that we can version control a database.

I have used a database project before but we had a batch file that we had to add to any scripts we wanted to be run. I didn't set this up and I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

We have just started using VS 2010 and would like to use that.

I am basically looking for any hints, tips, tutorials and general best practices for setting up and using a database project in VS 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the scripts issues, the database project will have folders called pre-deployment and post-deployment under the scripts folder.  Any custom scripts you need should be put there.  The database project can be used to create a database from scratch.  It can also be used, via a schema comparison, to generate change scripts to move from an older version of the schema to the current version.

You should start with [Microsoft's info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx) on how to work with database projects in VS2010.